# Problems with Stores - Sencha Touch 2.3 and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here's the fiddle

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#rDKXq

The controller does not have either of the getStore or the getModel methods.

Am I missing anything ?

Thanks!
Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Yes Bharat, you have missed extending the store. Add this in your store:

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Store'
```

Comment: I did that, but I am still facing the same problem. Here's the updated fiddle http://www.senchafiddle.com/#rDKXq#srNx2

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://www.senchafiddle.com/#rDKXq#srNx2#yB7GU Try this. storeId was creating the problem.